# How to make Ruby wait for mysqldump?

Tags: ruby, console, terminal, mysql

I want to assign the output of mysqldump to a variable, and use the generated output later.

#### Attempt 1:

```
    > 1.9.3-p125 :020 > x = `mysqldump falala` mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when
    > trying to connect  
    => "" 
    > 1.9.3-p125 :021 > x  
    => ""
```

Nope. X comes back empty, can't even check if there was an error

#### Attempt 2:

```
> 1.9.3-p125 :022 > x = system("mysqldump falala") mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> when trying to connect  
=> false
1.9.3-p125 :023 > x
 => false
```

Better. This way x has the information if the command was successful, but still no console output.

I'm still new to Ruby, but I think what happens is that Ruby continues to run without waiting for mysqldump to do its thing, but I really need that output (because in case an error happens, the script would mail the error/console output)

The full command I need to run is something like this
`mysqldump --host=#{host} --user=#{user} --password=#{pass} #{name} | gzip -9 > #{name}.sql.gz`

Comment: Do you still need some help with this?

Comment: Yep, still need help.
  My current solution is that I made a loop that checks 10 times (every 6 seconds) for a MySQL Dump file to appear (I don't expect to pull down larger databases than that for now), and if the file doesn't appear, I throw an error, otherwise I assume everything is OK.  
But I don't think that it's a real solution.  I'm not sure how the 'open3' method works with more advanced terminal commands (I mean multiple commands in one statement - `echo 'aa' | echo 'bb'`)

Comment: Have you looked at the pipeline method of the Open3 library?  It builds pipelines like the one you're describing.

Answer (score 5):

Both backticks and #system block the parent process until the child process exits.  #system only returns the exit status code.  Backticks return stdout only.  So you want to get stderr as well.  One way to do this is use [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html):

```
require 'open3'

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3('mysqldump', 'falala')

fail "An error happened: #{stderr}" unless status.exitstatus == 0
```

This approach obviously won't work well for large dumps, as the entire dump is slurped into the stdout variable.  To redirect mysqldump's output to a file, I recommend looking at [Process.spawn](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn).

Comment: `mysqldump` has an option `--result-file` which, if specified, will output the SQL to that file. This has the additional benefit of not mangling `CR` and `LF` in your data.

Comment: Using backticks can capture STDERR intermixed with STDOUT if the command sent to the sub-shell has `2>&1` appended to it. Sometimes that results in a confusing stream, but it's great for those quick and dirty times when the child app dies and you want to know why.

Comment: This is the full command that I run `mysqldump --host=#{host} --user=#{user} --password=#{pass} #{name} | gzip -9 > #{name}.sql.gz`, how is it going to work with all this ?

Comment: I agree with Tin Man about using redirection operators for quick and dirty grabbing of stderr.  As he notes, it can result in a confusing stream.  In those cases where I want separate stderr streams for each program in a pipe, I manually wire together their stdout and stdin with pipes in ruby, and capture individual stderr streams.  It's surprisingly little code to do this.